# Iterate list of dics in template

Tags: python, templates, django-templates, tornado

**clients_list**

```
   {'clients': [
    {'id': 357995, 'value': 1.0}, 
    {'id': 369743, 'value': 0.9}
    ]}
```

---

```
{% try %}
{% if clients_list %}
{% for client in clients_list %}
    {% for user in client %}
        {% raw user.id %}
        {% raw user.value %}
    {% end %}
{% end %}
{% end %}
{% except %}
{% end %}
```

Output expected:

```
357995
1.0

369743
0.9
```

The problem is that loop in template is wrong. How can i access the id and value?

This is a tornado template, but i think that is similar to django.

**Update:**

```
{% try %}
{% if clients_list %}
{% for client in clients_list %}
    {% raw client %} // outputs the clients_list
    {% for user in client %}
        {% raw user %} outputs 'clients'
    {% end %}
{% end %}
{% end %}
{% except %}
{% end %}
```

Comment: What is the actual output?

Comment: @kroolik If i do {% raw client %} in the first for i get clients_list with all data. In the second the output is just nothing to {% raw user.id %} and {% raw user.value %}

Comment: So `clients_list` is a list of dicts `{'clients': [...]}`?

Comment: @kroolik yes, as i said in the title. thanks :)

Comment: what's the output when you change `{% for user in client %}` to `{% for user in client.clients %}`?

Comment: @kroolik no, {% raw client %} will output nothing in the first loop. like {% raw user.id %} in the second too.

Comment: I've updated my comment midway, could you please check it? Previously, I've wrongly stated to change `{% for client in clients_list %}`, but having in mind `{% for user in client %}`.

Comment: @kroolik, sorry but no. The output is nothing. Maybe the update can help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the solution.

```
{% try %}
{% if clients_list %}
{% for client in clients_list %}
    {% for user in client['clients'] %}
        {% raw user['id'] %}
        {% raw user['value'] %}
    {% end %}
{% end %}
{% end %}
{% except %}
{% end %}
```